# Use a single mutex across multiple goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, mutex

I'm trying to reduce the amount of http requests my discord bot is making.

It's reading from an API.

With the fetched data it updates an internal database and outputs the changes.

Thing is: that database is different for every server the bot is in, and that's where I'm using the go routines. But, some servers need to fetch the same data, here is where I want to reduce the http requests. Right now I'm making requests regardless if I've already fetched a character. I want to create some sort of data that could be shared between the go routines and before making a request search within this data.

I was advised to use mutex. I'm trying. Original question: [Working with unbuffered channels in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958361/working-with-unbuffered-channels-in-golang?noredirect=1#comment111335894_62958361)

I made a skeleton of the real code I've tried: https://play.golang.org/p/mt229ns1R8m

In this example `master := make([][]map[string]interface{}, 0)` is simulating the discord servers.
`Chars` and `Chars2` would be the tracked chars for each individual server.
The char "Test" is mutual to both of them, so it should be fetched from the API only once.

It's outputing this:

```golang
[[map[Level:15 Name:Test] map[Level:150 Name:Test2]] [map[Level:1500 Name:Test3] map[Level:15 Name:Test]]]
------
A call would be made
A call would be made
A call would be made
A call would be made
Cache: [map[Level:150 Name:Test2] map[Level:15 Name:Test]]Cache: [map[Level:15 Name:Test] map[Level:1500 Name:Test3]]Done
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```golang
[[map[Level:15 Name:Test] map[Level:150 Name:Test2]] [map[Level:1500 Name:Test3] map[Level:15 Name:Test]]]
------
A call would be made
A call would be made
A call would be made
Cache: [map[Level:150 Name:Test2] map[Level:15 Name:Test] map[Level:1500 Name:Test3]]Done
```

But a new cache is being generated by every go routine. How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `Name` must be your cache key. Why are you keeping an array of maps?

Comment: @BurakSerdar `map[string]interface{}` is one char. A discord server can track multiple chars, therefore `[]map[string]interface{}`. And since the bot is in many servers, it ends up being `[][]map[string]interface{}`. Name is the only value of the char information that wont change, that's why I am using it to compare the local data to the fetched data. All other fields is where I am comparing if something has changed (level, vocation, achievements, etc).

Comment: If you're caching by char name only and don't care which server, use `map[string]map[string]interface{}`, so you can check if you have the char cached by checking `m[name]`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I tried this: https://play.golang.org/p/ChFMz13QJkW Still getting 2 caches instead of just one

Comment: You are creating a new cache for each server. Move cache creation outside goroutine creation.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many unknowns here for me to really write a proper design, but let's make a few notes:

- Try not to use `interface{}` at all, if at all possible.  In this case, it seems that it must be possible, though I'm not sure what the actual types will be.
- Try to make your data as simple as possible, but no simpler.  In this case, that *probably* means: have one data structure for "thing that talks to a Discord server" and a separate one for "thing that talks to the local database" (is this a caching database? if so, what are the criteria for invalidating a cache entry?).  But if one "character" (whatever that is—apparently a string) can have different properties per Discord server, that means that your index into your local database is not just a character, but rather a *pair* of values: the string value itself *plus* a Discord-server-identifier.

This might give you a functional interface like this:

```
var cacheServer *CacheServer

func InitCacheServer() error {
    cacheServer = ... // whatever it takes to initialize the cache server
}
```

(I've assumed lazy initialization of the cache server.  If you can do up-front initialization, you can drop the next test below.  Replace `ValueType` with the type of the result of a cached lookup of a name.)

```
func (DiscordServer ds) Get(name string) (ValueType, error) {
    if cacheserver == nil {
        if err := InitCacheServer(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    // Do a cache lookup.  Tell the cache server that if there
    // is no entry, it should return a NoEntry error and we will
    // fill the cache ourselves, so it should hold this slot as
    // "will be filled, so wait for it".
    slot, v, err := cacheServer.Lookup(name, ds.identity, CacheServer.IntentToFill)

    if err == CacheServer.NoEntry {
        // We have the slot held.  Try to look up the right info
        // directly in the Discord server, then cache it.
        v, err = ds.UncachedGet(name)
        // Tell cache server that this is the value, or that it should
        // produce this error instead of NoCache.
        cacheServer.FillSlot(slot, v, err)
    }
}
```

You might only want to cache *some* error types, rather than all; that's another one of those design questions that needs an answer that I cannot provide here.  There are other ways to do this that don't necessarily need a `slot` pointer return value, too; I've just chosen this one for this example.

Note that most of the "hard work" is now in the cache server, which definitely requires some fancy footwork.  In particular you will want to lock the overall data structure for a little while, use that to find the correct slot, then hold the slot itself so that other users of the slot must wait, while releasing the overall lock so that other users of *other* entries need not wait.  This introduces locking order constraints: be careful to avoid deadlock.  One method that should work is:

```
type CacheServer struct {
    lock sync.Mutex
    data map[string]map[string]*Entry
    // more fields
}

type Entry {
    lock        sync.Mutex
    cachedValue ValueType
    cachedError error
}
```

(You'll need some more types, like `Intent`—just two enumerated integers for now—below, and probably more fields in the above; this is just a skeleton.)

```
func (cs *CacheServer) Lookup(name, srv string, flags Intent) (*Entry, ValueType, error) {
    cs.lock.Lock()
    defer cs.lock.Unlock()
    // first, look up the server - if it does not exist, create one
    smap := cs.data[srv]
    if smap == nil {
        cs.data[server] = make(map[string]*Entry)
    }
    entry := smap[name]
    if entry == nil {
        // no cached entry - if this is a pure lookup, just error,
        // but if not, make a locked entry
        if flags == CacheServer.IntentToFill {
            // make a new entry and return with it locked
            entry = &Entry{}
            smap[name] = entry
            entry.lock.Lock() // and do not unlock
        }
        return entry, nil, NoEntry
    }
    entry.lock.Lock() // wait for someone to fill it, if needed
    defer entry.lock.Unlock()
    return nil, entry.cachedValue, entry.cachedError
}
```

You need a routine to fill and release the entry as well, but it's pretty simple.  You could, if you choose, make this a method on the `Entry` type rather than on the `CacheServer` type, as at least in this particular prototype, there is no need to use the cache server data structures directly.  If you start getting fancier with cache invalidation, though, it might be nice to have access to the `CacheServer` object.

Note: I've designed this so that you can do a cache lookup *without* an intent-to-fill, if that's useful.  If not, there's no reason to bother with the `Intent` argument.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing reply. So, here is the design: this char track is a plugin of the bot. If a server owner activates it, then it creates a DB. 
One of the fields on that DB is `[]Char` which is an slice of the proper char structure. The code I sent earlier is just an skeleton code mimicking what I'm doing with the real one.
Char errors, database errors, all that is handled already in the code. The code is working, my end goal here is just to reduce the amount of http requests.  (continue...)

Comment: Since it's reading from a game API, it is constantly changing. I fetch from the API every 10 minutes. When I get this new incoming data, I compare it to what I have stored internally. If anything has changed, I update the DB and send a msg to the corresponding discord server. 
What I need to do is: if server A fetches data for char XYZ, why should I fetch data for that same char again to server B, for example?
I need a cache, just while the go routines are working, and, before actually making an http request, check if the specified char has already been fetched. (Continue...)

Comment: With that, I could reduce the amount of http requests greatly. For example, I have a char that is being tracked in 12 different servers. Which means every 10 minutes I fetch that char 12 times. Totally a waste. I should be able to fetch it only once every 10 minutes and use the fetched data to all my servers. 
I'm thinking I'm probably going to change the bot design based on your reply and maybe make a "master" db that contains all chars that are tracked on every server and compare the newly fetched data to the discord server individually later. Will give it a thought. Thx again!